# No module named 'nltk'

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk

I successfully installed `nltk` and works fine. I have to run a file where `nltk` was imported and tensorflow too ,hence, i have to activate `tensorflow`.

When I activate `tensorflow` the .py file i want to run gives an error. I have read some solution but they didn't help.

```
HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```

this works fine but this does not

```
(tensorflow)HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~/AIG2018/Chatbot$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

What is that I am doing worng?

> ImportError: No module named 'nltk'

Comment: By activating tensorflow, do you mean you installed it using virtualenv? After activating the workspace, you could try to install nltk there: `pip install -U nltk`, and try to run your software again.

Answer (score 5):

You're using two different versions of python, and you probably installed `nltk` in your root environment, but not your virtual environment. When you "activate" the environment called tensorflow, you are using a different virtual environment, in which you haven't installed `nltk`. Try activating tensorflow, then using `pip install nltk`, then starting `python`. Because you seem to be using anaconda, this would probably look like this:

```
# Do these first 2 steps in your terminal:
source activate tensorflow
# you're now in the virtual environment called tensorflow
pip install nltk
# you now have nltk in that virtual environment

# Now, you can start python
python

Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
```

And you shouldn't have that error

Comment: Thank you but this does not return positive results. Look at my answer down.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at your messages you will see that the successful import of  `nltk` is on Python 3.6.3  and the failed import is on Python 3.5.2.

This indicates that you have two Python installations of different versions, and `nltk` is installed in one but not in the other.